# Why is passing an instance as self in method arguments bad practice?

Tags: python

We commonly see this syntax:

```
p = Person()
p.give_name('John')
```

but not this:

```
p = Person()
Person.give_name(p, 'John')
```

Is there any reason for this other than style? I generally know how self works and that it's passed implicitly in the first case, but are there scenarios where the second case may lead to errors or unexpected behaviors?

Comment: There's functionally no difference; it's mostly a style thing, as far as I'm aware. A legitimate use of it might be deliberately calling the superclass method on an instance of a subclass, from _outside_ said subclass. That said, I don't think there's an authoritative source or 'correct' answer for this, so I'm voting to close it as matter of opinion.

Comment: That’s not object oriented style. It more looks like the old days where people tried to emulated object orientation in imperative languages. Also I doubt that polymorphism will work this way.

Comment: Any source why is it considered a bad practice? Just quick idea about "duck-typing" `give_name` method accepting anything, not only instances of `Person` reveals that the second approach may have its use case

Comment: It's not bad practice. Who said that? For example if you wanted to convert a list of strings to uppercase using `map`, you would do `map(str.upper, L)`

Comment: Question edited to remove notion of best practice. I TA an intro class at my university. Other TAs and some of the instructors will correct students if they use the second case. Trying to learn if there is a reason to enforce conformation other than style.

Comment: Some reasons to use the first (conventional) form: (1) it's what people reading your code are used to, (2) it's more concise, and (3) consider this: `p = Potato(); Person.give_name(p, 'John')`. Now you have a person/potato hybrid, or the end of the universe, or something. Of course there are times when you need this superpower of calling a method from some other class, but why introduce the possibility of error in your everyday code?

Comment: BTW you wouldn't use that variable `p` in the class you teach, would you? I hope your actual code looks more like `person = Person(); person.give_name('John')`. This would help avoid the person/potato confusion. :-)

Comment: This question would be appropriate for the PSF python-list mail list, where opinions are allowed.  If there is a subtle difference other than typing 8 characters more or less, someone will likely say.  (I think that this may have come up there before some years ago.)